# Extracting most recent date from rows in a data frame

Tags: r, date, dataframe, extract

I am working with a data frame that has multiple dates that relate to each other but the bottom line is that I need to extract the most recent date. I have seen examples on here but nothing exactly what I am looking for. So my example data frame is as follows:

```
ID    date1    date2    date3
1   01/12/15 02/04/07 07/06/16
2   03/29/12 02/16/16 09/01/10
3   12/01/15 07/07/07 11/13/12
```

But what I want is to get an output that gives me:

```
ID    date1    date2    date3 max
1   01/12/15 02/04/07 07/06/16 07/06/16
2   03/29/12 02/16/16 09/01/10 02/16/16
3   12/01/15 07/07/07 11/13/12 12/01/15
```

I'm seeing people use plyr and dplyr but I am very unfamiliar with those packages. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I was able to run what was given by @akrun, but I ran into the issue of empty field dates. I have provided an example as follows:

```
ID    date1    date2    date3
1   01/12/15 NA 07/06/16
2   NA 02/16/16 09/01/10
3   12/01/15 07/07/07 NA
```

So with those empty spots I would still like the data frame to be transformed as following:

```
ID    date1    date2    date3 max
1   01/12/15 NA 07/06/16 07/06/16
2   NA 02/16/16 09/01/10 02/16/16
3   12/01/15 07/07/07 NA 12/01/15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert to `Date` class and then use `max.col` to get the column index, `cbind` with the row index, extract the elements from 'df1' and create the 'max' column.

```
df1$max <- df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1), max.col(sapply(df1[-1], as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%y"))+1)]
df1
#  ID    date1    date2    date3      max
#1  1 01/12/15 02/04/07 07/06/16 07/06/16
#2  2 03/29/12 02/16/16 09/01/10 02/16/16
#3  3 12/01/15 07/07/07 11/13/12 12/01/15
```

---

Or another option is `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`

```
df1$max <- apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) x[which.max(as.Date(x, "%m/%d/%y"))])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, date1 = c("01/12/15", "03/29/12", "12/01/15"
), date2 = c("02/04/07", "02/16/16", "07/07/07"), date3 = c("07/06/16", 
"09/01/10", "11/13/12")), .Names = c("ID", "date1", "date2", 
"date3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: Should have included in the examples but should this work with blanks in the dates as well? Or what should I do to circumnavigate this issue?

Comment: @RaviEulogio As the `as.Date("", "%m/%d/%y") 
[1] NA` returns NA and which.max removes the NA, the second option should work.  Regarding the first option, you may need a slight change in the code.

Comment: so for the second option I get the error when running the code `non-numeric argument to binary operator`, so not sure where to go from there

Comment: @RaviEulogio You have to update your post with a new example

Comment: Just trying to run the example that you previously used with the code `df1$max - apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) x[which.max(as.Date(x, "%m/%d/%y"))])` gives me that error

Comment: @RaviEulogio  I had a typo it should be `df1$max <- `

Comment: thank you so much this has been really helpful. I was able to run it except I had already converted the dates in date format and when I have that it gives me the error `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "max", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 13` which I know has to do with the date formats since I ran yours and saw that they were character strings. There is probably a simpler way but I was thinking of converting them all to strings again to successfully run the function.

Comment: @RaviEulogio  If you look at my code, I converted to `Date` format only to get the `max` value.  I think your data is somewhat different from the example showed.  Can you update your post with an example that gives the error?

Comment: @RaviEulogio  Using your new data, I get `apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) x[which.max(as.Date(x, "%m/%d/%y"))])
#[1] "07/06/16" "02/16/16" "12/01/15"`  Using the first solution `d1 <- sapply(df1[-1], as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%y");df1[cbind(1:nrow(d1), max.col(replace(d1, is.na(d1), 0)) + 1)]
#[1] "07/06/16" "02/16/16" "12/01/15"`

Answer (score 3):

Use `pmax` after converting to `Date` objects:

```
dat[-1] <- lapply(dat[-1], as.Date, format="%m/%d/%y")
dat$max <- do.call(pmax, dat[-1])

#  ID      date1      date2      date3        max
#1  1 2015-01-12 2007-02-04 2016-07-06 2016-07-06
#2  2 2012-03-29 2016-02-16 2010-09-01 2016-02-16
#3  3 2015-12-01 2007-07-07 2012-11-13 2015-12-01
```

---

Using `dat` as:

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, date1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("01/12/15", 
"03/29/12", "12/01/15"), class = "factor"), date2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("02/04/07", 
"02/16/16", "07/07/07"), class = "factor"), date3 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("07/06/16", 
"09/01/10", "11/13/12"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"date1", "date2", "date3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you feel more comfortable using SQL, the library `sqldf` provides you another way of getting the last date:

```
data1<-data.frame(id=c("1","2","3"),
                  date1=as.Date(c("01/12/15","03/29/12","12/01/15"),"%m/%d/%y"),
                  date2=as.Date(c("02/04/07","02/16/16","07/07/07"),"%m/%d/%y"),
                  date3=as.Date(c("07/06/16","09/01/10","11/13/12"),"%m/%d/%y"))


library(sqldf)
data2 = sqldf("SELECT id,
              max(date1,date2,date3) as 'max__Date'
              FROM data1", method = "name__class")
```